# Monitor microphone signal on a USB oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, microphone, sound

I would like to monitor a microphone signal on my cheap USB oscilloscope (LKHT00SU1.) I have tested it with a square signal generated from an Arduino.

[The microphone is a small one with a 3.5mm jack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00029MTMQ) (3 rings.) I have tested the microphone on my computer and it works.

With my computer, I generate a 400Hz sound through the speakers. I expect to be able to monitor it with my oscilloscope connected to my microphone.

I have amplified my microphone signal with a [HALJIA LM358](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B08BBYV1RG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) (signal amplifier bought on Amazon,) but I cannot observe anything.
Is it even possible to observe anything?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5kadi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What I see on the oscilloscope - I think it's just noise:
[image]

My final goal is to monitor sound with an MCU, I am not looking for a very clean signal.

Comment: Yes it's possible. What gain is the amplifier designed  for? Are you AC coupling correctly?

Comment: The amplifier can go from x1 to x100000. I am not AC coupling since I didn't know about it. From what I understand it allows to remove the DC component of my signal, So I will have the same noise but shiffted to zero right?
Shouldn't I also "rescale" the signal?

Comment: The microphone needs DC voltage to power it's built-in preamp. Look at it's data sheet, it should have a reference circuit. It's not a passive component. No power = no sound.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a link to the amplifier. And the microphone.

You are apparently using an electret microphone (hence the 2.2k\$\Omega\$ resistor) which will have a DC output of a volt or two if it's designed for 3V operation. You are also apparently using a DC amplifier with a gain of +20 (or 400 or 2000 or 10,000), so the op-amp output will definitely be saturated at the positive rail.

You need to bias the amplifier so the output is near the middle of the output range and AC couple the electret microphone to the input. Details depend on whatever schematic the amplifier has used or maybe  it's easier to buy an AC coupled module of some kind (presuming they are available).

Comment: I added the links. The 2.2kΩ resistor, I added it myself from what I saw in another post. Without the amplifier at all should I be able to visualize something?

Comment: You would need to set the scope to AC coupling. What's the highest sensitivity setting on the scope? Edit: NVM, I see it doesn't have any built-in amplification. One LS bit is about 80mV so that's almost 1/10 the sensitivity of what you need to see anything reliably.

Comment: The sensitivity of the scope is 78mV

Comment: So removing the amplifier and probing directly on the jack tip should give me something ?(I tried and nothing)

Comment: No it's way too insensitive. Might pick up tapping the mic gently with a pencil.

Comment: Your schematic and amplifier are wrong. The amplifier amplifies a very low DC voltage, not an AC microphone signal. You needs a microphone preamp circuit that amplifies the very low level AC from an electret mic (like yours) and also powers the mic. Lookup preamp circuit for electret microphone.

Answer (score 0):

Your amplifier is not intended for what you are trying to do.

You have an electret microphone.  It needs a small DC voltage applied to it so that it will work.

The microphone input on your PC supplies the needed voltage to the microphone.  Your amplifier module does not.

You would need a 2k resistor from 5V to the ring connection of the microphone, and a capacitor from that junction to the signal input of your amplifier.

I'll try to sketch something for you later.

Comment: The OP's circuit does show a microphone DC supply.

Comment: It shows power to the module and a resistor in series with the microphone input.  If you look up the module on Amazon, you will see that it is sold as a two stage DC amplifier and that it doesn't provide power to the microphone.

Comment: V3 is 5 volts for the module and V2 (via a 2k2) is power for the microphone.

Comment: Then there would be three wires.  There's only two.  The resistor is in series with the input.

Comment: Jack-tip and jack-sleeve are where the microphone connects (not very clear or explicit I know).